# Algorithm for Deductions

Tags: c++, python, c, algorithm

Here is the problem.

If we have two statements
`p=>q` and `q=>r`, it also implies that `p=>r`.

Given a set of statements I need to find whether a given statement is `true` or `false` or cannot be concluded from the given statements.

Example:
Given statements `p=>q, p=>r, q=>s`

- if the input is `p=>s` I should get the output `true`
- if the input is `p=>t` I should get the output `Cannot be concluded`
- if the input is `p=> ~p` I should get the output `false`

Here my question is what is the best data structure to implement this and what is the algorithm to use.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you just worried about the "implies" operator between atomic things? Or can you have more exotic stuff, like `~p or ~s and r`?

Comment: your question has a _hole_. you are missing somekind of an _input_ which we cant guess. p=>q , q=>r will imply p=>r given that your algebra system is transitive. still for an implication to be true (in normal propositional logic) there are certain inputs we need. something like `p was true and q was false, what is p=>q ?` . So please explain your question clearly.

Comment: p=>q means if p is true then q is true.

Comment: input or given statements can contain  p=true or q=false. but that may not be the case.

Comment: @Deamonpog The question does not really have a hole. It asks for a routine that decides whether a sentence can be formally proved given a theory (set of axioms). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Proofs_in_propositional_calculus

Comment: @BenDedee here ~p implies negation of p. I don't need  exotic stuff and I am not worried about implies operator.

Comment: Oh, sorry for misunderstanding. I was thinking about the Validity of Arguments. So what you are trying to do is check whether you can `validate` the given implication with the current implications you already have.(assuming the implications at hand are true)

Comment: Are you only interested in a system that implements the one deduction you've given (which is usually described as a double application of modus ponens, which is just one of many rules in a complete calculus)? Or are you interested in an implementation of a complete deduction system?

Comment: @us2012 I already implemented with vector of pairs. But what I am doing is generating all possible deductions and then see whether given statements is there or not. But is taking a lot of time because my input may have 10000 base statements.

Comment: @jogojapan I need the whole thing, but I need start somewhere right. :)

Comment: @Anil YACAS implements this, so you could look at their source for inspiration: http://yacas.sourceforge.net/refchapter14.html . (If you find an *efficient* algorithm for this, you'll get a PhD and invitations to conferences all over the world. Decidability of propositional logic is co-NP complete: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving#Decidability_of_the_problem )

Comment: I am not trying for any PhD. I have to solve this for another problem.http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/438101/dashboard#s=p3

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm still not _entirely clear on what you're trying to do. At the risk of being down-voted, I'm going to kick this out there and see what people think.

I might start by building a graph. Each entity (p, q, etc.) has its own node. "Implies" mean you draw a line between two nodes. Any input, then, is just a matter of seeing if you can find a way to traverse the graph--so in your example, a => b, b => c, the graph has three nodes, a connected to b, b connected to c. The fact that a path exists between a and c means that a implies c.

I haven't vetted this idea any further, but it seems like an interesting prospect. In particular because graph theory is cool, and lots of people are interested in it (i.e., Facebook execs). AND there are good modules in Python for analyzing graphs. (I assume the same is also true for C++. And you can always spec it out by hand using Gephi: https://gephi.org/)

Comment: This works as long as you allow *only* variable names and the implies operator in your language. As soon as you introduce a NOT `~` as the OP does, it is suddenly much more complex!

Comment: If it is to check whether a connection exists between two things it is ok, but I guess my question is more than that.

Comment: @Anil A simple graph based approach as outlined above will suffice if you are really interested in just the one deduction rule you gave. The reason is that you don't have any rules for structural expansion or reduction, e.g. you don't have rules like *`p=>r`, therefore `p and q => r` for any `q`*. Hence, you can treat all the `p`, `q` and even complex clauses like `p and q` or `p=>q` as _atomic_. But as soon as you introduce rules in the calculus that enable the structural modification of these atoms, a simple graph won't work because the structural mod rules would add graph nodes on the fly.

Comment: @jogojapan, and us2012: I've been fooling around with graph theory lately, and this was more of a brain storm than anything else. But it's such a nice idea that I was sure that someone else had come up with it hundreds of years ago. That being said, I'm actually a bit surprised that there isn't a way to dress up your graphs to account for more complex constructions. From dealing with mathematicians, I know to what lengths some will go to save a pretty idea :)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people have studied this problem many years. What you need is a [SAT Solver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT_solver#Algorithms_for_solving_SAT). Lookup [Chaff](http://www.princeton.edu/~chaff/software.html) or [zChaff](http://www.princeton.edu/~chaff/zchaff.html) or any other commonly used SAT Solver. You want to take your clauses like (p->q && q->r) -> (p -> r) and negate them and determine if that is satisfiable. If the negation is not satisfiable, then you have a theorem, something that is always true. If the original clauses are satisfiable and the negation of the clauses are satisfiable, the you should return "cannot be concluded". And if the original clauses are not satisfiable then you have something that is false.

This is actually a well studied problem. There are good algorithms, but there is a hard limit on how many propositional variables you can handle. SAT is at the heart of NP hard problems. A class of problems for which efficient algorithms are not known.

Comment: thanks, It is seems to be more than needed but I just needed to solve this problem.http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/438101/dashboard#s=p3 I will not have time to write all that code, because the contest for just two hours. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that given the simplicity of your problem, you could get away with using a simple `map`. The main advantage over a `vector` being in the much faster look-up.

```
// For "p":  { name: "p", positive: "true" }
// For "~q": { name: "q", positive: "false" }
struct Predicate {
    std::string _name;
    bool _positive;
};

using PredicateSetType = std::unordered_set<Predicate>;
using PredicateMapType = std::unordered_map<Predicate, PredicateSetType>;
```

You use the map in the following manner: when given `p => q`, you insert `{ "q", true }` in the set of predicates associated to `{ "p", true }`.

Note that this actually encodes a directed graph, so the typical methods of exploring a graph apply when it comes to proving a statement.

Comment: but "p" may not be true right? p=>q means if p is true then q is true.

Comment: @Anil: I don't care about `p` being true or not, the `_positive` attribute is there to distinguish between `p` (`{ "p", true }`) and `~p` (`{ "p", false }`) as indicated in the comment.

Comment: Then tell me how do I traverse through the map to tell a given statement can be concluded or not?

Comment: @Anil: the map is just a physical representation for a directed graph, you can do either a breadth-first or depth-first traversal for example (starting from `p` in a `p => r` statement, until you find `r`, `~r` or exhaust all possibilities).

Comment: Did you read all the comments? even if I implement this my running time won't change, how will this be faster than vector of pairs? The algorithm should work for 500 base statements.

Comment: @Anil: I did. 1/ It will be much faster than a vector of pairs because you'll get O(1) look-up with the hash map instead of O(N) look-up with the vector (assuming not sorted). 2/ Rather than generating all deductions (which requires a tremendous amount of memory) I propose (in my comment above) that you look at it *piece-meal* (using either recursion or a work-queue). I don't see how you could actually prove a *Cannot be concluded* property without examining all paths starting a `p` (to prove `p => r`) anyway, so the worst-case complexity seems fixed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24516/discussion-between-anil-and-matthieu-m)